# What number does $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\ln^k(1+\frac{1}{k})$ converge to?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, summation

What number does$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\ln^k(1+\frac{1}{k})$$converge to? I think it converges by root test$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(\ln^{k}(1+\frac{1}{k})\right)^{\frac{1}{k}}=\lim_{k\to\infty}\ln(1+\frac{1}{k})=0$$but I don't know what tricks I can use to find what this series converges to.

Comment: You can rewrite as $$\sum^\infty_{k=1}\left(\log(1+k)-\log(k)\right)^k$$

Comment: Wolframalpha gives an approximation of 0.8840530042897595.

Comment: Is there some reason for believing the closed form of the answer exists? E.g. is it taken from some textbook or problem list?

Comment: @Feanor I think you have a point. [ISC+](http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/index) can't find a symbolic representation of this approximation. I think that suggests there is no closed form solution?

Answer (score 1):

As $k\to\infty$, $\dfrac1k\to0$, so $\ln\bigg(1+\dfrac1k\bigg)\simeq\dfrac1k$ . Hence, $\displaystyle\sum_1^\infty\ln^k\bigg(1+\dfrac1k\bigg)\simeq\sum_1^\infty\bigg(\dfrac1k\bigg)^k$ converges. But, just like the latter, your sum does not possess a closed form expression either.

Answer (score 0):

If one has to be more formal when proving the asymptotic equivalence :

$$\forall\varepsilon>0\:\:\exists N_\varepsilon>0\:\:\forall n\ge N_\varepsilon\implies \left|\log_e\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)-\frac{1}{n}\right|\le \varepsilon\:\frac{1}{n}\\\iff\log_e\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\underset{+\infty}{\sim}\:\frac{1}{n}$$

Thus, according to $\text{WolframAlpha}$, the sum would be quite near below $\:\sum_{n\in\mathbf N}n^{-n}\approx1.29129$